# Is there a way to use more than one categorical variable for the hue command in seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn, hue, categorical

I am trying to create a stripplot of my variable of interest, separated by group on the x-axis, and colored according to sex.

| Treatment | sex | variable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Drug | male | 0.24 |
| Drug | male | -0.42 |
| Drug | male | 0.43 |
| Drug | male | 1.39 |
| Drug | male | 1.62 |
| Drug | female | 1.53 |
| Drug | female | 0.08 |
| Drug | female | 0.68 |
| Drug | female | 2.46 |
| Drug | female | 0.02 |
| Placebo | male | 1.74 |
| Placebo | male | -0.90 |
| Placebo | male | -2.39 |
| Placebo | male | -0.58 |
| Placebo | male | -0.95 |
| Placebo | female | 0.71 |
| Placebo | female | 1.47 |
| Placebo | female | -0.62 |
| Placebo | female | 0.73 |
| Placebo | female | 0.44 |

I use the following code to create the plot:

```
g = sns.stripplot(data = df, x = "treatment", y ="variable", hue = "sex", order = ["Drug","Placebo"],hue_order=["male", "female"], palette=dict(male="#466a6e", female="#76b4ba"), dodge=True)
```

[image]

However, I would like to use the green color shades for the Drug group and gray shades for the placebo group (i.e.: Drug Male = #466a6e, Drug Female = #76b4ba, Placebo Male = #706e6d, Placebo Female = #bfbcba) - is there a way to do that?

The closest I have come is to create a new column which concatenates the "treatment" and "sex" thus creating 4 levels to use for the hue command. Yet, this leaves me with the below plot where the strip plots are not aligned over the x-axis ticks:

```
df['Treat+Sex'] = df['treatment'] + df['sex']

g = sns.stripplot(data = df, x = "treatment", y = "variable", hue = "Treat+Sex", order=["Drug","Placebo"], hue_order=["Drugmale","Drugfemale","Placebomale", "Placebofemale"], palette=dict(Drugmale="#466a6e", Drugfemale="#76b4ba", Placebomale="#706e6d", Placebofemale="#bfbcba"), dodge=True)
```

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there now are 4 values in the `"Treat+Sex"` hue column, Seaborn will make space for 4 different dodge positions. The 2 for `Drug` will be placed at the left of the tick position, and the 2 for `Placebo` will be placed at the right.

Here is an alternative approach. You could create the `sns.stripplot` twice with a subset of the dataframe. Once for the `Drug` treatment and once for the `Placebo` treatment, each time with different colors.  The `order=` parameter will make sure everything is plotted on the correct position.

Note that `sns.stripplot` returns an `ax`, as it is an [axes-level function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions). The [tuple legend handler](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/legend_handler_api.html#matplotlib.legend_handler.HandlerTuple) can be used to help create a combined legend.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerTuple
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72165504')[0]

ax = sns.stripplot(data=df[df["Treatment"] == "Drug"],
                   x="Treatment", y="variable", hue="sex", order=["Drug", "Placebo"],
                   hue_order=["male", "female"], palette=dict(male="#466a6e", female="#76b4ba"), dodge=True)
sns.stripplot(data=df[df["Treatment"] == "Placebo"],
              x="Treatment", y="variable", hue="sex", order=["Drug", "Placebo"],
              hue_order=["male", "female"], palette=dict(male="#706e6d", female="#bfbcba"), dodge=True, ax=ax)

handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles=[tuple(handles[i::2]) for i in range(2)], labels=labels[:2], title='Gender',
          handlelength=3, handler_map={tuple: HandlerTuple(ndivide=None, pad=0.2)})

plt.show()
```

[image: sns.stripplot with two hue categories]